# Jquery create select drop down with selected option from another select

Tags: php, jquery

I have a dropdown select option and, I want to create a dynamic select dropdrown with selected option in a popup.

**Thanks in advance.**

```
    <div class="col-md-4">
    <select class="form-controlu" data-slide="2">
    <option data-strike="$250.00" data-per-usr="$225.00" >1 User</option>
    <option data-strike="$500.00" data-per-usr="$450.00" >2 User</option>
    <option data-strike="$250.00" data-per-usr="$225.00" >Add 1 User</option>
    <option data-strike="$500.00" data-per-usr="$450.00" >Add 2 User</option>
    </select>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4">
    <select class="form-controlu" data-slide="2">
    <option data-strike="$250.00" data-per-usr="$225.00" >1 User</option>
    <option data-strike="$500.00" data-per-usr="$450.00" >2 User</option>
    <option data-strike="$250.00" data-per-usr="$225.00" >3 User</option>
    <option data-strike="$500.00" data-per-usr="$450.00" >4 User</option>
    </select>
    </div>
    <select name="productUser" id="productUser"></select>

    <script>
      $(".col-md-4").click(function() {     
        var UserSelectedOption = $(this).find( ".form-controlu option:selected" ).html();   
        $("#productUser").html(UserSelectedOption);
      })
    </script>
```

Comment: You mean to say, You have two dropdowns and you want make a 3rd dropdown on the basis of above two ? Like if a user select one option from 1st dropdown and one option from 2nd dropdown, then it should be append to 3rd dropdown ?

Comment: No, I want to make 2nd dropdown on the basis of 1st dropdown with selected option from 1 st dropdown

Comment: But you do in fact have 2 selects already. Akhtar Munir asked a reasonable question. All you did was contradict. How about a better explanation, assuming you want help? Maybe you mean "I have 2 selects and whenever either of them is clicked on, I'd like my code to create yet another select based on something in the first." But it looks like that's not the case either. Looks like you have three existing selects already, and you want the contents of the third select to change somehow based on something in one of the two selects.

Comment: @Deepak_iise For example, if I select 1 option from 1st dropdown then it should be appended to 2nd dropdown. But will the previously appended option needs to be disappear from 2nd dropdown when selecting another one from 1st dropdown ?

Comment: Hi All, First two select box only for that reference that both .col-md-4 select have different options Ex If user click on first .col-md-4 than options in select#productUser if of first with selected option like <select name="productUser" id="productUser"><option>1 User</option>
<option  >2 User</option>
<option >Add 1 User</option>
<option >Add 2 User</option></select>If user click on second .col-md-4 than options in select#productUser<select name="productUser" id="productUser"><option >1 User</option>
<option>2 User</option>
<option>3 User</option>
<option>4 User</option></select>